¿Cómo puedo cambiar el delimitador de un archivo csv desde rstudio?
Tengo una base muy pesada en donde necesito hacer el reemplazo del siguiente delimitador: ||. Por lo general suelo cambiarlo desde el archivo csv, sin embargo, este pesa mucho y no he logrado hacerlo. Quisiera saber si existe alguna función que me permita reemplazar este tabulador.
He intentado abrir el archivo con delim, sin embargo, no me separa todas las columnas como debe ser:
Base_1 <- read_delim("Base/ConsultaI.csv", delim = "||", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
Base_2 <- read_tsv("Base/ConsultaI.csv")

Utilicé el siguiente código que encontré:
a <- function(src, dst, delim) {
  txt <- gsub(pattern = delim, replace = ";", x = readLines(src))
  writeLines(txt, con = dst)
} "

a("Base/base.csv", "Base/new.csv", "||")


Sin embargo, me sale el siguiente error:

Error in gsub(pattern = delim, replace = ";", x = readLines(src)) :
input string 2 is invalid
Además: Warning message:
In gsub(pattern = delim, replace = ";", x = readLines(src)) :
unable to translate '101||1                   ||CORPORACIN AUTNOMA REGIONAL DE LA FRONTERA NORORIENTAL - CORPONOR -                                                                                                                                                        ...' to a wide string


Si el separador es efectivamente el doble "pipe", es decir dos caracteres |, el problema es que las rutinas de lectura de este tipo de archivos, esperan que el separador sea un único caracter y no dos.
Pero, podemos ignorar esto y usar un único caractrer | como separador,  al leer el archvio se generaran columnas NA correspondientea a la que hay entre los dos "pipes", y estas columnas son luego, muy sencillas de quitar:
df <- read.table("Base/ConsultaI.csv", 
                 sep = "|")

   V1 V2 V3 V4                                                                V5
1 101 NA  1 NA CORPORACIN AUTNOMA REGIONAL DE LA FRONTERA NORORIENTAL - CORPONOR

Ahora, simplemente borramos las columnas pares:
df[, seq(1, by = 2, length.out = ceiling(ncol(df) / 2))]

   V1 V3                                                                V5
1 101  1 CORPORACIN AUTNOMA REGIONAL DE LA FRONTERA NORORIENTAL - CORPONOR


Siguiendo la lógica de @PatricioMoracho, pero considerando que tenés una tabla grande, podrías usar la función fread del paquete data.table para acelerar el proceso de lectura. Una vez leída la tabla y guardada como dat, por ejemplo, podés hacer una selección de variables con data.table que es más rápida que la propuesta de Patricio:
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("example.txt", sep = "|")
dat <- dat[, grep("^V", names(dat), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE), with=FALSE]
dat

Si, luego, lo querés exportar, entonces usá la función fwrite y ahí podés seleccionar el separador que te guste:
fwrite(dat, file = "mis_datos_con_nuevo_separador.csv", sep=",")

